# how to add new key value pair from frontend in API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

how would i add a new key value pair from frontend in API response

e.g

I have the following response :

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
  },
]
```

and I want to add  this key value pair ("completed": false) to make it look like the following response:

```
[ 
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
]
```

Comment: You can loop over with `map` and and a property to it

Comment: @decpk `.forEach` to mutate in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `map`.
and set `true`, `false` with the desired condition.

```
const newArr = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
  }
].map(v => ({...v, completed: true or false}))
```